# Compiling with Clang: Output only warnings?

Tags: linux-kernel, clang

When compiling the kernel, how can I have the compiler output only warnings?  Something like this:

```
arm:multi_v7_defconfig | Success in 1 minute and 5 seconds
warning: include/asm-generic/atomic-instrumented.h is out-of-date.
warning: include/asm-generic/atomic-long.h is out-of-date.
warning: include/linux/atomic-fallback.h is out-of-date.
warning: include/asm-generic/atomic-instrumented.h is out-of-date.
warning: include/asm-generic/atomic-long.h is out-of-date.
warning: include/linux/atomic-fallback.h is out-of-date.
net/ipv6/ah6.c:721:4: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
net/ipv6/esp6.c:856:5: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c:1075:27: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type '__u32' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wformat]
drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c:1076:4: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type '__u32' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wformat]
drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c:1242:12: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type '__u32' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wformat]
drivers/hid/hid-quirks.c:1242:26: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type '__u32' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wformat]
drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c:372:1: warning: format specifies type 'short' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c:377:1: warning: format specifies type 'short' but the argument has type 'unsigned char' [-Wformat]
drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_dp.c:51:9: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'u8' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_dp.c:51:17: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'u8' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_dp.c:51:25: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'u8' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_dp.c:55:9: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'u8' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_dp.c:55:17: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'u8' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau_dp.c:55:25: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'u8' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wformat]
```

The total build time is really nice as well.

Are these Clang specific features or will I also find them in GCC?

Comment: It's a default in Linux kernel if you didn't alter it. All other (non-warnings) lines are simple put in one wrapped line per call. But you may, of course, replace `$(quiet)` in *Makefile*. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Makefile#L52. Bottom line: it's not compiler option, it's per project settings.

Comment: Read also https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Makefile#L94.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks a lot!